# Eliminate Redirection malware in my website

Tags: web, redirect, spam, malware

I am experiencing a redirection malware in some of the subpages of my website. I tried deleting a script that´s been created by someone else. I use wordpress. But it still redirecting to that site. I don´t know how to fix it. It would like some help please.

In the console also appear messages like these:

www-widgetapi.js:1120 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://mysite.example').
q.sendMessage @ www-widgetapi.js:1120
googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id:1

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js:1

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
jsclou.in/pab1002.js:1

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysite.example/wp-admin/post.php?post=114&action=elementor' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://malware.example'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Any advice about this please?

Tried to delete the script where I found the site jsclou. It din´t solve it.
It look like this:

Comment: first, figure out how your wordpress was compromised. probably a vulnerable plugin or your wordpress is really old and unpatched. then, check out line `1307` in the  source code of the page you attached `(view-source:hxxps://estaciondemeteorologia.net/sainlogic-ft0300-ragova-r0835/)`. it has plenty of references to that website. a few script tags (that redirect to that site) and an iframe. delete them all.

Comment: Please do not post actual links to the pages on your website that have been infected with malware. In any case, this question is off-topic on StackOverflow as it's not a specific programming question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.